# How can I merge the last two commits?

Tags: git, git-merge, git-rebase

I want to combine my last two commits. Here is the result of `git log`:

[image]

Now I want to merge those last two commits *(which are into read box)* into one commit. How can I do that?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

There are many ways to do it (using `rebase` or `reset`).

The approach using [`git reset`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-reset):

1. No matter the approach, before anything else make sure the working copy is clean. Use [`git status`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-status) to find out. If there are uncommitted changes either save them in a stash ([`git stash`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-stash) or commit them on a temporary branch.
2. Run [`git branch backup`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-branch) to create a backup branch on the current commit.
   It is not really needed (the same result can be achieved using the [`reflog`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-reflog) or by writing down the hash of the current commit) but it is the easiest way to restore the current status if something goes wrong.
3. Run [`git reset --soft HEAD~2`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-reset#git-reset---soft).
   This moves `HEAD` two commits in the past (on commit `e8de117`) without changing the working tree or the index. The index and the working tree look now like they were just before you created the commit `6aa74e4`. All the files changed in the last two commits will be already added to the index. Because `HEAD` is on `e8de117`, the next commit will be created on top of `e8de117` (it will "replace" commits `6aa74e4` and `77c15d6`).
4. Run [`git commit`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-commit). You'll have to enter a new commit message.
5. If the result doesn't look like you expected ([`git diff backup`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff) should not report any difference) or if you have changed your mind, run [`git reset --hard backup`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-reset#git-reset---hard) to go back where you started from (actually, right after step #2).
6. If you are pleased with the output then remove the `backup` branch created at step 2 ([`git branch -D backup`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-branch)).
7. That's all.

Comment: I did it, however the final commit is wrong kinda .. I mean I expect it be contain some codes which are exist in one commit before the last one. thank you anyway.

Comment: can't git push the result.

Comment: IMPORTANT!! there is a mistake: after `git branch backup` you will be in the new 'backup' branch. You have to `git checkout master` (or the branch you are working).

Comment: @Ivan No. [`git branch`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-branch) does not change the current branch.

Answer (score 23):

You're looking for the `squash` feature of an interactive `rebase`:

Use `git rebase -i HEAD~2` to start an interactive rebase. In the opening editor, all commits that are part of the rebase are listed. In this case, since we provided the `HEAD~2` argument to the `rebase` call, we see two commits, each prefixed by `pick`. Not changing anything would lead rebase to `pick`, i.e. apply both commits, and nothing would be different. Instead, what you want to do is to `pick` only one commit, while `squash`ing the other one. This way, you squash the second commit into the first one, resulting in a single commit. When you safe and exit now, git will promt you for a new commit message, and voilà: a new commit containing changes from both of the older commits.

See [here](http://gitready.com/advanced/2009/02/10/squashing-commits-with-rebase.html) for detailed instructions.

As always when messing with history (as squashing different commits into a new one definitely is), you should only perform such operations on commits that you are sure nobody else based their work on.